# USB enumeration problem, cannot reply on request

Tags: microcontroller, usb, usb-device, lpc, arm7

I program with LPC2368 on ARM7 architecture and will configurate usb coonection with my pc. After initialization periphery and clock, i try to start usb. 
I am using the following scheme fro pull-up resistor in line D+:
[image: USB connection scheme]

For connection this pull-up, i change voltage-level on pin UCON from 1 to 0. After this i receive reset signal from host and message GET_DESCRIPTOR. Then i try to reply on request, but controller nothing sends. I think, problem in hardware. Maybe needed disconnect pull-up resistor after detecting my device?

Comment: When request from host received, i make "CLEAR BUFFER" on control enpoint 0, after write all data in transmit buffer and make validate buffer, but havn't interrupt from EP0_Tx.

Comment: Show your code, you have most likely a software problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe needed disconnect pull-up resistor after detecting my device?

No. The USB host would take this as if you disconnected your device completely.

Comment: And if i become reset signal from hub, then needed disconnect pull-up for 10 ms or not?

Comment: Not even when you get a reset from the host. BTW: An USB reset is normal behavior in the connection sequence. Suggest reading the USB specs at least once.

Comment: I read this documentation has at least three times, while searching for the cause